# Django - Filtering user information related to the URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 4 models: Blogger, User, Post and Comment.

Here is the blogger model.

```
class Blogger(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='bloggers')
    blogger_bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Now, I want to display username and blogger_bio depending to the URL.

For example, is someone is using: **/testuser**, the template will filter username and blogger_bio of only user named testuser.

How to filter this Dynamically?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic filtering? ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Use URL dispatcher in django to pass the username to your views. You can render the response template as you wish through views. Try it and post if there are any issues.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Comment: URL's are already created, but i want to display data in each page dynamically. Anything i can do with views or template?

Comment: You can then query the back end to get blogger bio value of corresponding user. Then pass it to the template which can be displayed using django template tags

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/

If this is not what you require, can you post the issue you are facing in implementation?